# Quarter Textpattern for a label in devexpress chart

Tags: c#, charts, label, devexpress, textpattern

I want to display quarter format for a label on xaxis in devexpress chart.
To do this,there's a property called **TextPattern** as following,

```
diagram.AxisX.Label.TextPattern = "{A:q}" ;
```

result would be : Q2-2016

But i want substring of above result, i.e. Q2

How can i get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do a trick to display only the first 2 characters, like this :

```
diagram.AxisX.Label.TextPattern = "{A:q}";
diagram.AxisX.Label.MaxLineCount = 1;
diagram.AxisX.Label.MaxWidth = 20;
```

You can change `MaxWidth` value depending on the size of your `Label`

Or you can use `CustomDrawAxisLabel` event of `ChartControl` like this:

```
private void chartControl1_CustomDrawAxisLabel(object sender, CustomDrawAxisLabelEventArgs e)
{
    AxisBase axis = e.Item.Axis;
    if (axis is AxisX)
    {
       e.Item.Text =  e.Item.Text.Substring(0,2) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to help you! Thank you too :)